# Microphone has low volume on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I was using windows 7. I could use the microphone at 50~60% and everyone could hear me perfect.
Now that I installed windows10, even if I'm really close to the microphone, the  volume bars doesn't move at all...
If I set it to 100% people can barely hear me.

I tried everything I found on the internet, which is not much... Please, any suggestion is welcome[image]

**EDIT**: Almost 3 years later and the problem remains. Someone from micro$oft thought it would be a good idea change the audio usb drivers and they messed it up on Win10. *Like everything else*

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting properties on the Microphone, and seeing if you can see what is shown as Front Mic in my second image, if it is there and has a check mark as shown, uncheck it.

[image]

Comment: Not a single customization :(  
Only: General, Listen, Levels, Advanced (Already uncked an option that let others softwares take control of the device).  

I Really don't know what else to try

Comment: Have you tested in another USB socked? if its in a front of case socket, try moving it to a rear / direct motherboard USB. if it is in a rear one, try moving it so its the only thing in a double USB socket. You havent said what software you were trying to use it with, but if it uses drivers, it may be worth looking to see if theres updated versions(if you havent already). Also have you tried using voice recorder to see if the mic will record in windows , without any other packages?

Comment: Thanks ! Tried everything without success. As it's PnP there is no drivers. Yeah, I use Open Broadcast to record and Stream. Inside the software, the mic volume goes up when I talk, while the windows manager doest move the bars. At the end, the recording has almost no audio...

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the PC in safe mode, then going into Device manager and removing usb devices/ seeing if theres any of the infamous yellow exclamation marks there? After removing any potential troubles Yellow exclamation marks,  or possible multiples of the samree usb device, make sure the Mic is unplugged, restart the PC and then plug it in and see if that helps.

Comment: I kind found the problem but there is no apparently fix for this.  Windows 10 % dB gain is really lower than Windows 7 % dB gain. Example: Windows 7 voume at 50% = +13dB while in windows 10, the same 50% is equal to +1dB. /Cry

Comment: Sorry to hear that., seems like a case of Windows 10 strikes again. However, last thing i can think of to try, is to go to Microphone propeties > Advanced and try unchecking 'Allow application to take exclusive control of this device'.